# select from multiple tables with jquery autosuggest

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli

I'm coding a website to learn more about PHP and am making a JQuery Autosuggest. The scripts  [here.](http://papermashup.com/jquery-php-ajax-autosuggest/)

Here's my code for the autosuggest.php:

```
<?php
 $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root' ,'***********', '**********');

if(!$db) {

    echo 'Could not connect to the database.';
} else {

    if(isset($_POST['queryString'])) {
        $queryString = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);

        if(strlen($queryString) >0) {

            $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM company WHERE name LIKE '$queryString%' LIMIT 10");
            if($query) {
            echo '<ul>';
                while ($result = $query ->fetch_object()) {
                    echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.addslashes($result->name).'\');">'.$result->name.'</li>';
                }
            echo '</ul>';

            } else {
                echo 'OOPS we had a problem :(';
            }
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    } else {
        echo 'There should be no direct access to this script!';
    }
}
?>
```

Now, instead of just searching for the name in the company table, I'd like to search for the **cat** field in a different table (called cat) and the **subcat** field in a different table than that ( in a table called subcat)

My table structure:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU9NQ.png) (I can't post pictures yet)

So I want to search from three tables. Is this possible and how can I do it with my code?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Have you *tried* searching all three tables, then combining the results and printing them? You're asking if it can be done, but don't mention whether you tried in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do a `UNION` between each of the 3 tables and normalize the data into `Name`, `ID` and `Type` columns.

Comment: Thanks I did and fixed the problem.